# <Link> to same page including query Parameters

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a Link router in react which looks like this:

```
<Link to={window.location.href}>Name</Link>
```

But this just redirects to: http://0.0.0.0:4321?name=applehttp://0.0.0.0:4321?name=apple

I want to just redirect to same page including the queryParameters.
I tried using # but it neglects the queryParameters.

Ideally like this: `http://0.0.0.0:4321?name=apple`

Comment: There is not need of `<Link >` , you can use `<a href >` for this.

Comment: `<Link>` is for internal navigation, i.e. within the App. I u want to navigate to some other page, you should use `a`.

Comment: The `Link` component is for internal linking, don't use a raw anchor `<a />` tag. Please share a more complete code example for what you are trying to do. If you are linking to a page you are already matching and rendering then likely you need to implement the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method or use one of the RRD hooks or listen for changes on the route props and handle accordingly. We can't help much more than this without seeing your code though.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the location of the page with `useLocation()` from `react-router-dom`.

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
.
.
.
    
let location = useLocation();
```

Now you can use

```
<Link to={location.pathname}>Name</Link>
```